# Connect to PostgreSQL running in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Flask application running with an instance of PostgreSQL using docker-compose.  How can I connect to the database in the terminal?

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        links:
            - postgres
        env_file:
            - .env
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.4
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: user
            POSTGRES_USER: password
            POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
```

Comment: You haven't included any of the code from your flask app, nor the actual error you are encountering. This docker-compose.yml file looks fine on its own, although the `links:` section is unnecessary.

Comment: I only want to connect to my psql instance through the terminal so no need for any flask code...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the postgres above the web app.

```
version: '2'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.4
        # container_name:
        #    - my_postgres_1
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        # links:
        #    - postgres
        env_file:
            - .env
```

After running `docker-compose -d up`. You can access the postgres via `psql` by running this Docker command. Please get your postgres container name, i.e `my_postgres_1`

```
docker run -it --rm --link my_postgres_1:postgres postgres psql -h postgres -U postgres
```